# A list of plotting functions in base R?

Tags: r, plot

Each time I encounter a new plotting function in Base R (e.g., `dotchart()`, `smoothScatter()`. `matplot()`), I wish there was a list of plotting functions in Base R which I could refer to for various plotting cases.

## Question:

I was wondering if any our colleagues might be aware of **a list of plotting functions in Base R** which I could refer to for various plotting cases?

Comment: Downvoter, could you please explain the reason for downvoting this simple question?

Comment: I'd like to know the reason as well.  The OP didn't deserve that.  This is a valid question; I even provided an answer.

Comment: You could use library(help = "graphics"), that will display the list of plotting functions in R e.g.: hist, mosaicplot, persp, plot, etc.

Comment: @ed_sans, thank you very much.

Comment: @JLH The down-vote is probably because this is not a programming question, and is out-of-scope of StackOverflow (not my downvote, although I have voted to close this question for being off topic).

Comment: @SymbolixAU I respectfully disagree.  If someone had asked, what are all the ways I can print in C that surely would have been regarded as on-topic as "programming-related", even if it reveals inadequate prior research.  This question is no different, OP wanted a way to know all the ways his language of choice could output results.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use

```
 library(help = "graphics")
```

that will display the list of plotting functions e.g.:

```
...
barplot                 Bar Plots
box                     Draw a Box around a Plot
boxplot                 Box Plots
boxplot.matrix          Draw a Boxplot for each Column (Row) of a
                        Matrix
bxp                     Draw Box Plots from Summaries
cdplot                  Conditional Density Plots
clip                    Set Clipping Region
contour                 Display Contours
coplot                  Conditioning Plots
```

Answer (score 0):

I found this site [R plot gallery](http://www.r-graph-gallery.com/) that has a wide array of basic types.  Click on them to see the numerous variants and the function call for each.